# Python function isn't returning variable

Tags: python

I'm doing a python exercise and writing my first function in which I have to return a value... But the value isn't being returned. I'm running the .py file through Terminal on OS X with Python 3.2.3. The final line should be different to the fourth final line, but they are coming out the same. Yet if I print textMessage in the function itself it prints fine.
What am I missing?

```
def caesarEncipher(textMessage, shift):
    listOfChars = list(textMessage)
    length = len(listOfChars)
    count = 0
    while length != count:
        listOfChars[count] = chr(ord(listOfChars[count])+shift)
        count = count + 1
    textMessage = ''.join(listOfChars)
    return (textMessage)

print ("Please enter your message to cipher:")
textMessage = raw_input()
print ("Please enter the value you wish to shift your message by:") 
shift = int(input())
print "Your original message was:"
print textMessage
caesarEncipher(textMessage, shift)
print "Your message adjusted by a shift of", shift, "is:"
print textMessage
```

Comment: At the moment, this isn't a Caesar cipher.  What happens if you try to shift the word `"zombie"` by 1?  You'll get `"{pncjf"`.  You need to shift *among letters*, not just increment the value that `ord` returns by `shift`.  Think in terms of wraparound..

Comment: Incidentally: `ceasarCipher = lambda msg, shift: ''.join(chr((ord(i)-97+shift) % 26 + 97) for i in msg.lower())`

Answer (score 8):

You need to ***save*** the value returned by your `caesarEncipher()` function.

So *instead of this*:

```
caesarEncipher(textMessage, shift)
```

*have:*

```
textMessage = caesarEncipher(textMessage, shift)
```

Right now the method *is* returning a value, but it's not being saved, and therefore can't be displayed in your subsequent `print` statement. Once you assign the return value of the function to a variable (in this case `textMessage`) you can use it.

Answer (score 6):

It does. You have to catch it into a variable.

```
textMessage = caesarEncipher(textMessage, shift)
```

Anyway, Caesar would not encipher it this way. If you `shift` the value of the letter `Z` by a positive number, you are already out of the alphabet and returning some other characters.

You can use this method (works for lowercase characters only):

```
import string

def caesarEncipher(textMessage, shift):
    src_chars = string.lowercase
    dst_chars = string.lowercase[shift:] + string.lowercase[:shift]
    return textMessage.translate(string.maketrans(src_chars, dst_chars))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You return the value. but you don't do anything with it.  You need to store the returned value when you call the function:

```
textMessage = caesatEncipher(textMessage, shift)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're never storing the return value of `ceaserEncipher`.  To store the value, you do:

```
new_text_message=ceasarEncipher(textMessage,shift)
```