# PRAW: Python can print Reddit comment variable but not return it

Tags: python, python-2.7, reddit, praw

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980180/python-cant-return-a-variable-but-can-print), [a second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485999/python-function-isnt-returning-variable) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766900/function-iterates-with-print-but-not-with-return) about mixing return with loops and lastly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469812/i-can-print-a-local-variable-but-not-return-it-python-2-7) about returns, but they don't apply here.

**Problem**: I can print the date of comment, but I can't seem to "return" it properly. Ultimately, I need to add the dates to a list.

```
import datetime
def get_date(submission):
    time = submission.created
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time)

authors_list = []
date_list = []

# Problem is here: 
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    authors_list.append(comment.author) # works fine!
    date_list.append(get_date(comment)) # does not work

print authors_list 
print date_list # does not work
```

I expect the date list to return

```
[2013-06-22 12:28:54, 2014-06-22 12:28:54, 2015-06-22 12:28:54]
```

But instead I get:

```
[datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 22, 3, 4, 7), datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 22, 10, 33, 47)...]
```

**What I've tried:**

Tried saving the date to a variable within the loop, but it doesn't work: (I get the same output as above)

```
date_list = [ ]
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    a_date = get_date(comment)
    date_list.append(a_date)
print date_list

>>> [datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 22, 3, 4, 7) ...]
```

How do I fix this? And can anyone explain why this happens? Thanks!

Context: If its of any relevance, I'm using `praw` v5.2.0 to extract data from the Reddit API.

Comment: have you tried printing the returned list?

Comment: Your definition of "doesn't work" seems a bit misleading. Your question is actually about converting a datetime to a string?

Comment: The thing you "expect the date list to return" is not a valid Python literal. You're getting a list of datetimes, which is what you seem to want, so what's the *problem*?

Comment: @LSelter yes, printing the returned list returns the desired answer (ie. 2013-06-22 12:28:54 ... ). However I want to append it to a list and I can't do that if I'm just printing the result

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had a function to convert the dates to "dd-mm-yyyy", which works when I print it. the _problem_ is that it's not returning this same format when I try to return(?) with `date_list.append(get_date(comment))`. Why does the format change, and how can I change it back? (edit) sorry if this question sounds awkward, I'm not sure how to phrase it

Comment: You may be being confused by the fact that when you print a datetime directly you see the `str`ing format, whereas when you print it inside the list you see its `repr`esentation format. But they're the same object; if you want strings, you need to be explicit about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and you just want to store the string representation of the datetime object try this:

```
# Problem is here: 
for comment in submission.comments.list():
    authors_list.append(comment.author) # works fine!
    date_list.append(str(get_date(comment))) # should now work as expected
```

In your original code you added the  `datetime.datetime` object you your list and returned the, apparently you are after just having a list of strings, so wrapping you `get_date()` call in a `str()` call achieves this. although it may be better to do this later if you still need access to the `datetime` object functionality later, outside of this function. and convert to string at the point of use.

Comment: thanks!! It works :-) If you have a moment, do you mind explaining what went wrong with mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert datatime.datatime object to String adding strftime to return sentence.

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```